# How to learn PHP, Jquery, Javascript, in smooth way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im taking classes for programming for about 1,5 years now and started from 0. I must say for my feelings I already learned allot but still it is not enough to build anything complex on my own without using examples from the internet that I just modify and try to make it work.

I did some courses on CodeCademy and watch youtube guides and google allot, use certain websites like w3schools and more of that. But what is the best method to learn any givin language in a propper way. Im spending allot of time on searching and reading things that I never seem to fully understand, only sometimes some parts of it.

It does make me lose the hope that I wil ever be a good programmer and feel demotivated.

What are your expiriences and tips and tricks for a beginner like me ?

Comment: Contributing to a project.

Comment: Read books, lots better then schools and work in projects

Comment: Read [`Head First`](http://www.headfirstlabs.com) books, the best programming books I know!

Comment: Don't lose hope and make `lots of lots of mistakes` and more importantly **learn** from them.

Comment: Get some books, a decent browser, a working internet connection and off you go!

Comment: Get example code and modify it. Try to understand each line, lookup the functions in the docs then start with simple tasks like an ajax powered guestbook and move on after you feel confident.

Comment: Find a live class online. You can find one at [Tutoslive](http://www.tutoslive.com)

Answer (score 2):

This question is rather opinionated, not sure it is suitable for StackOverflow.

For what its worth, this is my advice:

Ask lots of questions, make lots of mistakes and build things, keep challenging yourself. Never give up. Also, learn to use some frameworks, for PHP, Symfony, Yii, CakePHP, for example. For JavaScript, Angular, Backbone, Node.

[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php)  and [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)  are your best friends :)

Also, install a testing server on your local machine such as [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Good luck!

Comment: and TBH you should be putting this on the comment section :)

Answer (score 0):

I was in same situation as you before.
As mentioned already contributing to project is a good way to learn as it will give you motivation to push yourself forward and do it because you don't want to let your team down.

Another great way I have found for myself is to create a small projects yourself, for example:

I want to create my own website, what do I need? I need to know: html, css, js and php.
Okay so start with what I can do.

When you reach PHP and JS part, you will face problem which you can break down into smaller problems it will also develop your problem solving skill in IT.

Answer (score 0):

As an intermediate programmer myself, I would say the best way to learn is to continue finding resources online and communicating with other programmers or developers.

Some words of advice:

> 1.) Never be afraid to ask for help 
>   2.) Don't feel discouraged, feel inspired 
>   3.) Believe in yourself

Also, this website is probably the best resource I've found, both for information and kind people.

Comment: Thanks Karl-André for fixing my post, a great example of what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some idea's of something that you yourself miss on the internet. Start with that, work out that idea as a concept and then start it.

Read a lot of IT-related news items; they might inspire something for you to start thinking about doing.

Contributing to projects has already been mentioned, but I'll do it as well. It has many advantages, not in the least having people in the project focused on achieving whatever the project has set out to do, which might give specific insights in that field of the wild internet.

Get a part-time job at a web-developers company, it doesn't have to be big, but it does offer you opportunities to learn specific areas. There's always work in the IT sector.

Also, troll along the questions asked on Stackoverflow, see if you find something that might challenge you and go attempt to answer it. The questions are usually abstract enough that you can replicate the problem someone is having, then try and document your solution for them.

Answer (score 0):

In my long (yet short ;-) ) programming experience, it's a matter of perspective. Some learn better learning the whole theory from books and then applying examples, and then making sample projects. In this case use JQuery, PHP and JavaScript tutorials for basic concepts and then make some examples of the methods, and then, try to make a project on your own. But then again, this is one perspective.

The other and it's been kind of direct to me, it's that if you have already some basic programming skills, go ahead and do something you like. When you have doubt about doing something, google it, read docs try, and try again. Why this is smooth? Because even though it's not as fast, the experience will remain solid. If you're the practical type of person, you won't easily forget when you learned something out of try & error.

There are other perspectives, but I'll leave it from here. I wanted to be helpful somehow on this because I had this same question before. But, faithful to the rules ^^u (yeah, rules... ¬¬u), if it's a question that derives from perspective, debate, or recommendation (like product benchmark, or best educational way of learning something) then should not be addressed here. A specific question for an specific answer. Try to make it specific, and search in the similar question matches just in case. Good luck =)